# NSTextField - Selectable and mouseup event

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have created my own NSTextField object:

```
@interface MyTitleLabel: NSTextField
@end

@implementation MyTitleLabel
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"up");
}
@end
```

then initialised it like this:

```
MyTitleLabel* title_field = [[MyTitleLabel alloc] init];
```

The problem is if I have:

```
[title_field setSelectable:YES];
```

the `mouseUp` event is *not* triggered. But if I have it set to `NO` it is. However I need the `NSTextField` to be `selectable` and have a `mouseUp` event?

I also have an issue where `- (void) rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)event;` is not called once I have selected some text in the `NSTextField`.

Comment: What is your end goal?  It sounds like you want to listen to when your `MyTitleLabel` becomes the first responder.

Comment: I want my nstitlelabel to behave identically to how a HTML link works. I currently have the ability to click on it **or** select the text of the label **not** both

Comment: Use `attributedStringValue` and an attributed string with a `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute.

Comment: @Willeke yeah but i don't want the user to be able to edit it...

Comment: Set `editable` to `NO`.

Answer (score -1):

The functionality of text fields is implemented by NSTextFieldCell, which does most of the work, and the control which owns it, NSTextField.

In addition, while editing, the field editor comes into play.

Apple’s documentation explains this relationship:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html